# Bio-metric passport

Tags: visas, passport-renewals, ukraine, biometric-passports

I would like to know if a country l visited frequently with my old UK bio-metric  passport would have access to my past history on my new bio-metric passport.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they have access to your travel history, or at least you should assume that they do.

Biometric passports do not store travel history in any form other than stamps on the page.  In other words, immigration authorities do not write data to the chip in the passport when you use it.  The country may, however, have stored records of your travels in their own systems.  Since you probably can never be certain that they did not do so, you should assume that they did.

It is generally trivially easy to find records stored in connection with your old passport using the data in your new passport.  To retrieve the records, they have your name, date of birth, and possibly place of birth, along with other biometric identifiers.  Some of these will match exactly with your old passport; for the vast majority of travelers it's probably enough that the name and date of birth match.